# How to find name of the virtual machine Ubuntu server is being hosted on?

Tags: command-line, server, virtualbox, virtualization, virtual-console

Is it possible to find out what version and what type of virtual machine is my ubuntu server being hosted on its on a remote server?-Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can give [virt-what](http://people.redhat.com/~rjones/virt-what/) a try. It is a shell script that can detect most common VMs types. It's avaliable in the official repos, just an apt-get away.

```
sudo apt-get install virt-what
sudo virt-what
```